# ASP.NET MVC5 Bootstrap 3 Modal Form not validating client-side and is posting back to page

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an MVC5 application that I am just starting to do some Ajax on.
I have a page with a button which when clicked opens up a Bootstrap modal with a form from another action. However, when that modal form is submitted, the jquery unobtrusive validation is not being called and the page redirects to a partial view on a blank page, instead of inside the modal dialog.

So, 1: How can I get jquery validation to work inside the modal,
and 2: How can I make the form not refresh the page, but reload the returned view into the modal?
and 3: I'm confused by how Ajax.BeginForm is supposed to work as I would assume it wouldn't create a page refresh.

Here's the page which contains a button to load the modal:

```
@using Plus.ViewModels
@model UserViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Personal Details";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
// A separate form here

<div class="form-actions">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
      <i class="fa fa-save"></i>
       Save
    </button> |

 <a class="btn btn-primary" href="@Url.Action("ChangePassword", "Manage", new object{})" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Change Password</a>

</div>
}


<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
            jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.parse($(this));
        })
    </script>   
}
```

The View that contains the form I want to submit inside the modal dialog:

```
@model Plus.ViewModels.ChangePasswordViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Change Password";
    Layout = "";

    AjaxOptions options = new AjaxOptions();
    options.HttpMethod = "POST";
    options.Url = Url.Action("ChangePassword", "Manage");
    options.UpdateTargetId = "modalForm";
    options.InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace;
}

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ChangePassword", "Manage", null, options, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    <div id="modalForm">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Change Password</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.OldPassword, new { @class = "col-md-6 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.OldPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.NewPassword, new { @class = "col-md-6 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.NewPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "col-md-6 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Change Password</button>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

The Controller for the actions:

```
public ActionResult ChangePassword()
{
    ChangePasswordViewModel cpvm = new ChangePasswordViewModel();
    return PartialView(cpvm);
}

//
// POST: /Manage/ChangePassword
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> ChangePassword(ChangePasswordViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return PartialView(model);
    }
    var result = await UserManager.ChangePasswordAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), model.OldPassword, model.NewPassword);
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        return Json(new { success = true });
    }
    // Failed
    AddErrors(result);
    return PartialView(model);
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Answer of 1st question :-** Just Include JS files i.e `Jquery Unobtrusive js` file in your partial view which you are opening as modal then it work fine ,some times this problem comes in partial view in asp.net mvc.

Just include this js file in your Partial View also :

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

or try this in Partial View:

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($("form"));
```

**Answer of 2nd and 3rd question :-** As I have seen in your question you are already using `Ajax.BeginForm()` so it should not reload the page while submitting the form ... just check that you have included **jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js** js file or not.

And also add below code in `web.config` file:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
  <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

Comment: Thank you! #1 is fixed. I thought it would have loaded from the master view but it obviously doesn't.

#2, I already am using @Ajax.BeginForm, so I thought it should be working, but that's why I have question 3

Comment: I don't have jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js. Weird, I thought it would be bundled with a new .NET MVC5 project.

Comment: @RhysStephens..that is the reason for your problem just add js file and everything will be ok..thanks..

Comment: Thank you! It is all working now. So it does make sense to me #3, now that it's actually working!!!

Answer (score 1):

Adding my grain of salt to the discussion, in case someone else needs a *similiar* solution. Unlike the original question, the added validation files used at the bottom of the layout worked for me. The problem was somewhere else.

I was missing some lines of code after showing the modal, inside the ajax request (in the success part of the call).

##### From controller:

- `public virtual PartialViewResult GetModal() { }`
- To the ajax call: `return PartialView("~/Views/Example/EditForm.cshtml", viewModel);`

##### To view:

```cs
/* ajax call was made, the partial view is received */

// After successful call, insert the partial view form into the modal
$("#modalFormContainer").html(result);

// Show the modal
$('#myModal').modal('show');

// Apply frontend validation
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.parse($(this)); // This fixed my problem.
})
```

My problem was that the frontend validation was totally skipped, and the form was submitted directly to the backend (`Save` post method in the controller). That line of code fixed the problem.